# Raspberry Pi GPS to HTML + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, gps, raspberry-pi

I currently have a Raspberry Pi with a GPS dongle which is successfully getting coordinates. I can see all the information i need if i run cgps -s and my ultimate goal is to display this in a HTML page. I am currently using NodeJS as a server.

How can I access the GPS information from either a webpage or the NodeJS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run a Linux command in a NodeJS application using [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('cgps -s',
(error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!